# kinect calibration parameter

Tags: calibration, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use openni sample viewer to view the kinect images, I find that the depth can mapped on the color image. But I did not find the camera intrinsic and transfer parameters of the kinect. Can kinect provide calibrated images directly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9771/kinect-calibration-parameter/) by [Bruce](https://answers.ros.org/users/224/bruce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While the point cloud is "calibrated", there is no internal mechanism in the driver to output rectified images. However, you can use [image_proc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_proc) to do this.
[This answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/299/getting-the-calibration-parameters-of-the-kinect) is about where to get the parameters.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1